# Undefined resolved data while accessing nested view

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-ui-router

I try to integrate Firebase on a simple AngularJS project based on UI-Router sample.

This seems to works pretty well using navigation flow... but actually a got an undefined variable while accessing directly the nested view with for example the direct url : #/contacts/42

You can test and see the source code on the following plunker : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/1CnwHl9rsOifzWoSYg8V?p=preview

As you can see in firebug I got the following error : 
Error: contacts[i] is undefined

Contacts is a variable of the factory 'ContactDB' which is promised from firebase backend and resolved data of the state 'contacts'.

It seems $scope.contacts is corrupted. Only the first item is set...

I really don't understand the reason of this issue... ?!

It would be really GREAT if somebody can help me.
Thanks in advance to have a look.

Comment: Does this issue occur even off Plnkr? (eg when you are running on localhost).

Comment: Yes, It happen on both Plunker and localhost... I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using ui-router and firebase and having issues trying to get the number of contacts to display on state route change. I am using numChildren() in my contacts controller.

```
.controller( 'contactsCtrl', function contactsCtrl( $scope, filterFilter, orderByPriorityFilter, contacts, FBURL ) {
  var contactsRef = new Firebase(FBURL+'/contacts');
  $scope.entryLimit = 50;
  $scope.search = $scope.lastSearch.search;

  contactsRef.on('value', function(snap) {
    $scope.contacts = contacts;//contacts is a resolved $firebase Object
    $scope.contactsCount = snap.numChildren();
  });


  $scope.$watch('search', function(oldTerm, newTerm) {
    $scope.filtered = filterFilter(orderByPriorityFilter($scope.contacts), oldTerm);
    $scope.contactsCount = $scope.filtered.length;
    $scope.lastSearch.search = oldTerm;

    //sets contacts list page to 1 on new searches
    if (oldTerm != newTerm) {
      $scope.contactListPos.page = 1;
    }

  });

});
```

This works fine if you load the /contacts route from the browser bar or refresh the page. But if I change states from say my /home state which has a link to go to /contacts, $scope.contactsCount will display 0. I also have a $watch in the search input, only when I do a search does the contactsCount update. contactsCount will also update correctly when I go into a contacts.detail child state and then back to the contacts state.

I was able to get it working by editing the $watch callback using if/else statement:

```
if (newTerm === oldTerm) { //first run
  return;
} else {
  $scope.contactsCount = $scope.filtered.length;
}
```

Comment: It seems like the $watch on the search input is setting $scope.contactsCount back to 0.